# External Monitors shut off when Laptop Lid closes

Tags: 11.10

I have researched the solution...

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac "nothing"
```

does not fix it. I have two external monitors and when I close my lid the settings are reset and the laptop's monitor is set to the default.

Thanks!

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-ac false  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery true  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 10  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 1  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 600  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 600  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac false  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'   
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery true  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 120  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200  
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 11.10 these should force your lid close action to **nothing**.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active 'true'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
```

(*optional*)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power battery-action 'nothing'
```

The first one will make sure that GNOME's power daemon is taking care of the power settings and not some other process.

The second will define the close lid action to **nothing** when the laptop is plugged in to the power supply and the optional 3rd the same but in case you are running on battery.

---

### Further available options and tools

Use this command in a terminal to have a look at all the available power options

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

this will list all the options and their current set values. To set them up to a different value use the command

```
gsettings set schema [:path] key value
```

For more information on the `gsettings` tool check the man page.

Optionally you can install the `dconf-tools` package and use the `dconf-editor` tool for graphically checking and changing those options.

[image]

Install it via the Ubuntu Software Center ([dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools]) or via a terminal with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.

Comment: Alright I followed that exactly. Everything checks out. I restarted my computer even and I still am running into the same problem. Its driving me crazy.

Comment: Try changing button-sleep and button-suspend also to nothing, some laptops might get close-lid with those actions. No need to restart, changes should be automatic.

Comment: Yup did that too... I don't know whats up. I miss the old Ubuntu.

Comment: Add the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` to your question please.

Comment: It's up there now.

Comment: I had the same problem. The answer did at least solve mine. Good luck to finding a solution to the original poster